# WordPress, add a lightbox and a lightbox gallery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, lightbox

I am looking for a plugin, which I can set an image in the CMS to popup when a link is clicked on the webpage. for example, I could have "If you click *HERE*, an image would appear which the user has selected in the CMS.

I looked into https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-lightbox/screenshots/ but this seems to only be creating a lightbox from the image on a page?

EDIT:

Here's my code @Noobskie

```
<a href="<?php $image = get_field('map_town');
    if( !empty($image) ): ?>
    <img class="hovereffect" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" width="100%" height="235"/>
    <?php endif; ?>"rel="lightbox[uniqueID|filename]" title="my caption">Test</a>
```

Comment: Anyone got any idea.

Just to clarify. I need to be able to add a lightbox and lightbox gallery. 

So, I could add a lightbox to an image, but this image should NOT be able to slide through, or add a gallery, and add a selection of images which can be slide through

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/lightbox-plus/

There are hundreds of lightbox plugins you just need to search this was on the first page of google and does what you need

From there docs

> Add a rel="lightbox[uniqueID|filename]" attribute to any link tag to
>   activate the lightbox, include a name between square brackets in the
>   rel attribute. For example:
>
> ```
> <a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[uniqueID|filename]" title="my caption">image #1</a>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have 2 questions my friend.

If I want to let the user select the image in the CMS, how would this work. I tried the following:

<a href="<?php $image = get_field('map-town');
if( !empty($image) ): ?>
<img class="hovereffect" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" width="100%" height="235"/>
<?php endif; ?>"
        rel="lightbox[uniqueID|filename]" title="my caption">image #1</a>

Comment: I assume you would have to change `lightbox[uniqueID|filename]` to the appropriate values its hard for me to know without seeing your code

Comment: I added it to the OP. I think it is very close, but I think it isnt syntax correct.

Comment: Anyone got an idea? Feel this is seriously close

Comment: That's not it. It doesn;t seem to like the way it is entered, as if its trying to read it as all HTML or all PHP

Comment: Where are you trying to put the code in at? The wordpress back end or a php file?

Comment: `<a href="<?php $image = get_field('map_town');?>">
 <?php
 if( !empty($image) ): ?>
  <img class="hovereffect" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" width="100%" height="235" rel="lightbox[uniqueID|filename]" title="my caption">Test
  <?php endif; ?>
</a>`

few closing brackets were missing

Comment: Now it displays nothing.

Can't believe i'm having so many issues just to get the lightbox image to open an ACF field. Thank you for sticking by me, we can do this!